# Chess board in c

Tags: c, matrix, chess

I was wondering how can i make a c program that only prints the black positions on a chess board for example:
**- = (empty space);**

-| A8 - C8 - E8 - G8 -
-| - B7 - D7 - F7 - H7
-| A6 - C6 - E6 - G6 -
-| - B5 - D5 - F5 - H5
-| A4 - C4 - E4 - G4 -
-| - B3 - D3 - F3 - H3
-| A2 - C2 - E2 - G2 -
-| - B1 - D1 - F1 - H1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 8;

    int i,j;
    char a[100][100] = {
        "A8"," ","C8"," ","E8"," ","G8",
        " ","B7"," ","D7"," ","F8"," ","H7",
        "A6"," ","C6"," ","E6"," ","G6",
        " ","B5"," ","D5"," ","F5"," ","H5",
        "A4"," ","C4"," ","E4"," ","G4",
        " ","B3"," ","D3"," ","F3"," ","H3",
        "A2"," ","C2"," ","E2"," ","G2",
        " ","B1"," ","D1"," ","F1"," ","H1",
    };
    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < n;j++){
            printf("%c ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about writing code that prints all of the squares. Only then do you worry about printing only half of them.

Comment: Please edit the post and include the code there.

Comment: @kiner_shah it prints only the top row A8 C8 E8 G8

Comment: I think you have got the concept of 2D character arrays wrong.

Comment: @kiner_shah how should it look like ?

Comment: You have a lot of basics wrong. Even in as little code as this. You can't use the `%c` on a string. But more importantly, you seem not to grasp that you don't need to fill a matrix with strings, all of the square names can be determined programmatically by their coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the comments marked with `// CHANGE HERE`.

`char a[100][100]` creates 100 character strings each of max length 99 (1 character for null terminator `'\0'` (Imagine 100 rows with 99 columns)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //int n = 8;  // CHANGE HERE - unused

    int i;

    // CHANGE HERE
    // 1. Replaced ' ' with '  ' (two spaces)
    // 2. Added '  ' after G for white H column cells
    char a[100][100] = {
        "A8","  ","C8","  ","E8","  ","G8","  ",
        "  ","B7","  ","D7","  ","F8","  ","H7",
        "A6","  ","C6","  ","E6","  ","G6","  ",
        "  ","B5","  ","D5","  ","F5","  ","H5",
        "A4","  ","C4","  ","E4","  ","G4","  ",
        "  ","B3","  ","D3","  ","F3","  ","H3",
        "A2","  ","C2","  ","E2","  ","G2","  ",
        "  ","B1","  ","D1","  ","F1","  ","H1",
    };
    
    // CHANGE HERE - chess board has 64 cells
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        // CHANGE HERE - print a new line after every 8 entries
        if (i != 0 && i % 8 == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%s", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no reason to use a 2D array here.
Representation on the screen and memory layout of data structures don't need to match. As an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if ((((i % 8) + (i / 8)) & 1) == 0) {
            printf("%c%u ", 'A' + (i % 8), 8 - (i / 8));
        } else {
            printf("   ");
        }

        if ((i % 8) == 7) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code isn't pretty but it works. It doesn't even use an array.
All you need is some operations like division and modulus to determine row and column. Then you need to notice that squares with coordinates (X,Y) share the same color if X+Y is even.

The code isn't pretty, but it uses very simple logic. As an exercise, within the `for` loop, try to get the coordinates X and Y into separate variables. Then it might be easier to understand.